# Docker / Wordpress Container PHP Fatal Error when installing wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx

When I load up wordpress for the first time, I get the following error in the wordpress log:

`wordpress    | NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /var/www/html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 706`

I have set up the following docker-compose script:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    # Pull latest image
    image: mysql:latest
    # Set container name
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    # Set restart policy
    restart: always
    # Set environment variables
    env_file: .env
    # Set environment
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
    # set volume
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    # PHP and WP image wont support MYSQL newer auth default and therefore adjustment to autehnticate the app is needed
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    # define networks
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  wordpress:
    # ensures that the container will start in order of dependency
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    # Pull latest image
    image: wordpress:6.2.0-fpm-alpine
    # Set container name
    container_name: wordpress
    # Set restart policy
    restart: unless-stopped
    # Set environment variables
    env_file: .env
    # Set environment
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    # set volume
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    # define networks
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  webserver:
    # ensures that the container will start in order of dependency
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    # Pull latest image
    image: nginx:1.23.4-alpine
    # Set container name
    container_name: webserver
    # Set restart policy
    restart: unless-stopped
    # Set ports
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    # set volume  
    volumes:
      # mount WP app code to /var/www/html, as root in the nginx server block
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      # mount nginx config on the host to relevant dir on container
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      # mount certbot config on the host to relevant dir on container
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    # set network
    networks:
      - app-network

  certbot:
    # ensures that the container will start in order of dependency
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    # Pull latest image
    image: certbot/certbot
    # Set container name
    container_name: certbot
    # Set volumes
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    # Webroot tells certbot to use the webroot plugin to place files in the webroot folder for auth. Define path of webroot, preferred email for registration and agree to agreements. No-eff-email is used to prevent certbot from sending emails to EFF. Staging is used to test the process without hitting rate limits. Finally, define the domain name
    command: certonly --non-interactive --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email sebastian.scharf@retronexus.net --agree-tos --no-eff-email --force-renewal -d retronexus.de -d www.retronexus.de

# When docker creates volumes, the contents of the volume are stored in a directory on the host filesystem, /var/lib/docker/volumes, thats managed by docker. The contents of each volume then get mounted from this directory to any container that uses the volume. 
volumes:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:
  certbot-etc:

# Enables our containers to communicate with each other since they are on the same network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And the following nginx.conf:

```
server {
    # Listen on port 80
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # defines server name and server block that should be used for requests to the server
    server_name retronexus.de www.retronexus.de;

    # specifies webroot for certbot renewal requests to the .wellknown/acme-challenge dir. includes rewrite directive that directs http requests to the root dir to HTTPS
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}

server {
    # HTTPS enables ssl and https2 and includes SSL cert and key locations and certbot security params
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name retronexus.de www.retronexus.de;

    # defines the files that will be used as indexes when processing requests to the server.
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Names the root directory for requests to the server.
    root /var/www/html;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/retronexus.de/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/retronexus.de/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    # Security headers
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;

    # check for files that match individual URI requests.
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # Pass control to index.php. Will handle PHP processing and proxy these requests to the container. 
    # FastCGI cinfog and independent PHP processfor for PHP requests via php-fpm
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    # Handle htaccess files since NGINX won't serve them. deny all directive ensures that htaccess files will never be served to users.
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # ensures that favicon.ico requests are not logged in the access log.
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        allow all;
    }

    # Block unts off logging for static assets requests ans ensures assets are highly cacheable.
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

I am running: wordpress:6.2.0-fpm-alpine (latest) and mysql latest version.
I restarted the docker service and reinstalled the containers. Though I have the latest versions, i cannot get the setup to run.

Comment: I don't think you're actually running `wordpress:6.2.0-fpm-alpine` -- that image has PHP 8 and the code referenced by that error doesn't exit in the indicated file. Run this and post the output: `docker exec -it wordpress head -706 /var/www/html/wp-includes/script-loader.php | tail`